# What are the reasons against unloading DOM elements for infinite scrolling?

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I've been studying different approaches of infinite scrolling. I've looked at Facebook and Twitter both don't seem to unload DOM elements at all. To date they simply block you from loading more than a certain number of content items. I find this surprising, especially for their mobile versions where memory is more constrained than on desktop.

What are the reasons against unloading DOM elements for infinite scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

So that you don't have to load them again if the user scrolls back up, in combination with why bother

Comment: Yes, almost like you would save images in cache so they don't get pulled down again and again

Comment: Ok - but I think especially on mobile devices it is worth bothering due to the hardware constraints. The facebook mobile web app does not unload items and fills the phone memory to 500 MB.

Comment: @bengro The Facebook team seems to disagree.  You asked why other people don't do it; that's the answer.  You can go ask them on IRC if you like; they're quite available.  You are welcome to constantly load things in both directions if you want to.

Comment: What if you have a situation where the browser slows down because you have so much data that needs to be rendered. For example logs.

Comment: you do not have that situation.  browsers can display multiple gigabyte files without slowing down.